# how to use 'Replication in typeorm'

Tags: replication, typeorm

I want to setup read/write replication using TypeORM. Example of my replication connection settings: file -> ormconfig.js

```
import Config from './src/config'



module.exports = {
  type: 'mysql',
  logging: true,
  replication: {
    master: {
      host: "asdasd.amazonaws.com",
      port: 3306,
      username: "rwdev",
      password: "RWss4t3dev",
      database: "SysDev"
    },
    slaves: {
      host: "asdadasd.rds.amazonaws.com",
      port: 3306,
      username: "rodev",
      password: "ROss4r34ddev",
      database: "SysDevRead"
    }
  },
  entities: ['src/repo/entities/*.ts'],
  migrations: ['src/migrations/*.ts'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: "src/migrations"
  },
  subscribers: ['src/subscriber/**/*.ts'],
  extra: { connectionLimit: 10}
}
```

and then when I start running "yarn start" on my code and got an error 
**"unhandledRejection TypeError: this.options.replication.slaves.forEach is not a function"**.
I'm still new at doing this "replication" with typeorm, so any help would be appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeORM expects slaves to be an array, therefore you get the error "forEach is not a function". So you just need to wrap it:

```
module.exports = {
  replication: {
    ...
    slaves: [{
      host: "asdadasd.rds.amazonaws.com",
      port: 3306,
      username: "rodev",
      password: "ROss4r34ddev",
      database: "SysDevRead"
    }],
    ...
}
```